# Handling of condition objects in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, handler

What exactly happens in

```
tryCatch(warning("W"),warning = function(c) cat(c$message))
```

As far as I understand this the call `warning("W")` creates a condition object `c` of type `warning` and then someone (who?) looks for a handler (where? and recognizes the handler how?) and calls the handler on `c`.

The task of `tryCatch` is only to "establish" the handlers. What does this mean? In short the question is: how exactly does the condition object get to its handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, `tryCatch` is used to catch and either ignore or specifically handle errors and warnings. While you can do `warnings` with this function, I see it more often used with `withCallingHandlers` (and `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")`).

The [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) book is a good reference for many topics; for this, I'd recommend two chapters:

- [Exceptions and debugging](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html), where Hadley highlights one key difference:

  > `withCallingHandlers()` is a variant of `tryCatch()` that establishes local handlers, whereas `tryCatch()` registers exiting handlers. Local handlers are called in the same context as where the condition is signalled, **without interrupting** the execution of the function. When a exiting handler from `tryCatch()` is called, the **execution of the function is interrupted** and the handler is called. `withCallingHandlers()` is rarely needed, but is useful to be aware of.

  **Bold** emphasis is mine, to highlight that `tryCatch` interrupts, `withCallingHandlers` does not. This means that when a warning is raised, nothing else is executed:

  ```
  tryCatch({warning("foo");message("bar");}, warning=function(w) conditionMessage(w))
  # [1] "foo"
  tryCatch({warning("foo");message("bar");})
  # Warning in tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) : foo
  # bar
  ```
- Further details/examples are in the [Beyond exception handling](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html) chapter.

`tryCatch` executes the expression in a context where anything "raised" is optionally caught and potentially altered, ignored, logged, etc. A common method I see is to accept any error and return a known entity (now without an error), such as

```r
ret <- tryCatch(
  something_that_fails(),
  error = function(e) FALSE)
```

Unlike other operating systems that allow precise filters on what to handle (e.g., python and its `try: ... except ValueError:` syntax, ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), R is a bit coarser in that it catches all errors you can get to figure out what kind of error it is.

If you look at the source of `tryCatch` and trace around its use of its self-defined functions, you'll see that ultimately it calls an R function `.addCondHands` that includes the list of handlers, matching on the names of the handlers (typically `error` and `warning`, though perhaps others might be used?). (The source for that function can be found [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b6280636ca7425aef97938cf553da574cb82f9d8/src/main/errors.c#L1629), though I don't find it very helpful in this context).

I don't know exactly how to answer *"how exactly ... get to its handler"*, other than an exception is thrown, it is caught, and the handler is executed with the error object as an argument.

Comment: if we match the class of the condition on the name of the handler then we can only have the distinction message/warning/error/condition. But we can define our own conditions as arbitrary S3 classes, are they then all dumped into the handler specified in condition = ...?

Comment: The *Beyond exception handling* chapter holds all the answers. Unfortunately the text isn’t entirely understandable unless you already have a deep understanding of continuations and related Lisp/Scheme concepts. (This isn’t a criticism of Hadley or Peter; this stuff is simply *hard*.)

Comment: gcc, I'm not certain if/how to define our own types of Exceptions, to be honest. That is a great question, though I suspect it won't go far enough to make it a *rampant* and broadly useful thing until R-7.0 (sarcasm) when perhaps most/all errors are specifically sub-classed for precise handling.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, while many C/C++/C# programmers giggle a little when I say I *"program in R"*, they aren't completely wrong in one sense: many constructs in other languages that are considered fundamentally required (including exception handling) are not nearly as robust or flexible in R. The flexibility afforded by its higher-level functions are quickly negated when the shiny app goes gray. (I worked with lisp and scheme (remember [scsh](https://scsh.net/)?) as an undergrad, and even then didn't fully grok "unrolling continuations".)

Comment: @r2evans I’m not sure why you’d say this in this particular context. I mean, I agree in general (I’m a huge proponent of better type checking and modularisation than is possible or advocated for in R). But R’s condition handling is best-in-class. The underlying mechanics are hard but they’re hard in a “high-level maths” kind of way, not because they’re badly designed. And knowing them is unnecessary for the general usage of conditions, which works better than most modern exception systems because it’s monadic.

Comment: Good points. My statement is not meant to be inflammatory, perhaps it is more aimed at "many (most?) R users are not formal programmers, so R's imprecise exception handling is often not used or not used correctly/well". Either way, I see how what I said comes across as crude or mis-guided. Thanks. (And I certainly did not mean to suggest that the functions are not done correctly ... just not as fine-tuned-controllable as other languages.)

Comment: BTW @KonradRudolph: if you'd care to look at it, I have a suggested snippet on codereview on which I'm trying to invite commentary: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225419/error-specific-trycatch. It's not well tested in the field, still rather "alpha".

Comment: @r2evans I see, I think there’s a misunderstanding since R *does* allow S3 subclassed conditions. The issue is just that almost nobody (including the entire base R codebase, AFAICT) uses them. But they work, and they’re great.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for clarifying that. Yes, and while your [other comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225419/error-specific-trycatch?noredirect=1#comment439443_225419) and [code](https://gist.github.com/klmr/ca110f867c059616ae88d76ceee9d47e) perfectly demonstrate the capability, it's rarely seen in the wild. I think there are many moves in tidy-packages to be a bit more surgical, but that is far/beyond normal use (by users). Heck, `withCallingHandlers` is rather difficult for me to grok and use well, outside of `invokeRestart("muffleWarnings")`.

Comment: @r2evans I freely admit that I understand neither `withCallingHandlers` nor `invokeRestart` entirely, despite having used them extensively in [this abomination](https://gist.github.com/klmr/d10623a0b4c7e1e9a6523eebee4913d1) and in a piece of code which implemented continuations. Like I said, they’re simply conceptually *hard*.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Gargantuan effort/accomplishment. And a little dizzying. `yield` in R would be ***awesome***. (Especially if written entirely in base-R instead of relying on `foreach`. This is not a challenge, not sure how trivial it would be, nor where it would be used. [Bravo zulu](https://www.navy.mil/navydata/questions/bzulu.html)!)

Comment: Thanks all. I finally figured out that  even if all S3 class conditions other than message/warning/error end up in the condition = ... handler this handler can be a generic method which dispatches on the class of the condition, so its not really a limitation.